# What data type I should use in DTOs when internally I'm using Noda Time Instant?

Tags: asp.net-core, nodatime

In my domain objects I'm using Noda Time Instant to represent date time related data.

In my REST API I'm using plain C# classes as DTOs which represent request and response contracts. They are tranformed to JSON using the default ASP.NET Core pipeline. As I want to use date time related data in those DTO I wonder which data type should I use:

- string - assume that it is in ISO 8601 format
- long - assume that it is Unix Epoch
- DateTime
- Instant - not sure how to do that properly

What is considered as the best practice in this case?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question.  Are you asking about a data type in your C# classes, or are you asking about the JSON representation?  If the classes, what's the problem using `Instant`?  Or are you looking to have your DTOs not take a dependency on NodaTime?

Comment: I was initially testing it with the built-in swagger and it didn't work like I was expecting.

Comment: I'm still confused why an `Instant` won't work for you, but you might consider using either a `DateTimeOffset` with the offset set to zero, or a `DateTime` with the `Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Utc`.  The difference comes out in serialization, where the former emits a `+00:00` and the latter emits a `Z` (like `Instant`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a string in ISO-8601 format. Indeed, that's what the JSON serialization libraries (`NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet`, `NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson`) use by default - so you should be able to keep using `Instant` within your .NET DTO, but the value will still be transformed to a string in the JSON.

Comment: I was misled by the default swagger page generated by ASP.NET Core which showed Instant as object. After some configuration using microelements.swashbuckle.nodatime the swagger page works with strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's depend on what kind of Noda time you use.

If you use the zone format, use **ZonedDateTime**, if use local time, use **LocalDateTime** as the type.

And to your needs, you can use string to get the json data, this is a demo,use zone format:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public ZonedDateTime mytime { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Here(string myModel)
    {
        MyModel myModel1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(myModel);
        return new JsonResult("Ok");
    }
```

View:

```
@model MyModel 
<input id="time1" value="@Model.mytime"/>
<button id="btn1">send</button>

@section Scripts
{
<script>
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    var myData = { mytime: $("#time1").val()};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/Here",
        data: { myModel: JSON.stringify(myData) },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
</script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The question specifically says it's about the Instant type... so I'm not sure where ZonedDateTime and LocalDateTime come in.